# Make VIM function return text without indent

Tags: vim, scripting, macros, indentation

I guess this question could be taken in two ways...

1. (Generic) - is there a way to specify settings 'local' to a function (`setlocal` changes seem to persist after the function call)...
2. (Specific) - I have a function which gets called from an `imap` mapping (which takes a user input to pass into the function. The function works perfectly if I run `set paste` or `set noai | set nosi` either just before running my shortcut, or added into the function itself. The problem is, whichever way I do it, those setting changes persist after my function call.

Essentially, my workflow is:

1. In insert mode, type `////` at which point I get prompted for input text, which I enter and press enter.
2. The function is called with my input. I need the function to disable indenting, return my string and then re-enable the previous settings. The string would just be a PHP-block comment like this:

   ```
   /**
    * Blah {INPUT TEXT}
    */
   ```

Any suggestions appreciated. My script currently looks like this:

```
function CommentInjector(txt)
  return "\/**" ."\<CR>"
  \    . " * foo " . a:txt . " bar " . "\<CR>"
  \    . " */"
endfunction
imap <silent> //// <C-R>=CommentInjector(input("Enter some text:"))<CR>
```

---

### UPDATE

Managed to figure it out at least how to dump a comment in... Would appreciate knowing how to get/restore settings though...

```
function! CommentInjector(txt)
  set paste

  exe "normal! i/**\<CR>"
  \          . " * fooo " . a:txt . " bar\<CR>"
  \          . " */\<Esc>"

  set nopaste
endfunction

map <C-C><C-C><C-C> :call CommentInjector(input("Enter some text:"))<CR>
```

Using this you can just pres Ctrl+C 3 time, enter text when prompted and you get a nice comment written in. It assumes you had "set paste" disabled before running though...

Comment: So if you `set nopaste` at the end of your function you still have `set paste` after the function is run? For the generic question, I think you are looking for `let`, see `:help let`. Also did you try SnipMate or SnippetEmu? They do almost exactly what you want to do and more.

Comment: But anything after the `return` wont get run, thus leaving it enabled. Is there any way to return content without leaving the function? Maybe `normal`....?

Comment: Added an update for a working comment injector.

Comment: The way I do this sort of thing is with an iabbrev; I write the whole comment block (and it assumes autoindent will work as normal) and just leave the cursor on the second line.  (The last bit of my abbrev is `<C-O>k`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've posted an update and are really just looking at how to save/restore settings, I'll give a general solution.

- At the start of your function save the initial value of the setting: `let save_paste = &paste`
- Make any changes to `paste` that you'd like to make
- Restore it at the end: `let &paste = save_paste`

An example of this can be found in the documentation with `:help use-cpo-save` where they talk about saving and restoring the value of `cpoptions`.

Comment: Does the ampersand on paste imply a reference (rather than by-value)?

Comment: It's a reference to a Vim option. So you can use for saving and restoring optios values or simply changing them

Comment: @lucapette is correct.  The second part is documented at `:help let-&` but I'm not sure about the first.  I've just always known it as getting the value from an option.