# Return to default settings for the next tabs after function finishes in vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to write a couple of my personal function in vim to set some filetype related stuff to be set when files of that type is loaded. A function that is executed when shell file is detected is below. But I found, that all of the specified in that function settings will be applied for all opened tabs. For example, a regular text file will have number option set resulting in unwanted line number. Is there is a way to return vim to default settings for all tabs except that with corresponding filetype?

```
autocmd FileType sh call Bash_source()

func! Bash_source()
  set number cursorline
  set shiftwidth=4

  map <F9> :w \| :!./%<CR>
  imap <F9> <Esc> :w \| :!./%<CR>

  map <C-C> :call ToggleComment('#')<CR>
  imap <C-C> <Esc>:call ToggleComment('#')<CR>li
endfunc
```

Expected behavior: function settings are applied only the tab with corresponding filetype.
Actual behavior: function settings are applied to all tabs, opened after function executed.

Comment: Do you know the difference between `:set` and [`:setlocal`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#:setlocal)? Also you can [save/restore settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8125918/7976758).

Comment: setlocal worked out, thnks!

Answer (score 0):

`:setlocal` is a solution to the original question.